# Delay when storing currentTarget in redux state, devtools stops updating

Tags: reactjs, redux

I used to store the open/close state of some popovers in its own local state. Then I moved it to redux, to be able to control many popovers. And it works.

But I needed to store the "anchorEl" (currentTarget) position of the popovers too. But when I try to add the currentTarget in the reducer, it takes some time for the popover to appear, and no actions appear in redux devtools (stops working?). But the popover does appear in the right position, so it seems that the reducer is storing the open/close and position correctly, but it takes too long (it goes better after the first click, but too slow the first time).

So I wonder why the delay happens, and why redux devtools stops working, and is there anything wrong in the code?

I start the action from the view component :

```
handleClickItem(e, termId) { 

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault(); 

         this.props.toggleOpenMenuItem(id, e.currentTarget);
```

The popover gets open/close state and position from redux:

```
<Popover 
        open={this.props.openState}
        anchorEl={this.props.anchorEl}
```

The action:

```
export const toggleOpenMenuItem = (id, currentTarget) => {
    return({
        type: TOGGLE_OPEN_MENU_ITEM,
        payload: {id, currentTarget}
    });
};
```

Reducer

```
case TOGGLE_OPEN_MENU_ITEM: 

        var openState = true;
        if(action.payload.id in state.menuItems) {
            openState = !state.menuItems[action.payload.id].open;
        }

        return {
            ...state,
            menuItems: {
                ...state.menuItems,
                [action.payload.id] : {
                    open: openState
                    currentTarget: action.payload.currentTarget
                }
            },
        };
```

if I console log the currenttarget, it gives  `[object HTMLLIElement]`.

If I don't add the currentTarget to the state in the reducer, the popover still opens slowly, but the action does appear in the reducer (though after another delay). So it seems like there is some problem sending the `[object HTMLLIElement]` with the action?

**edit**:
I realize I could probably store the anchorEl in the local state. I only need to control the open/close state with redux. Still I wonder what the problem is.

Comment: Actually it's a not good idea to store HTML Element in the redux store.

Comment: The state should be a plain object, but HTML Element itself has methods as well as property fields. So, I think you should save query-selector of it's element.
But the better way is keep `anchorEl` in Component's state.